# How does Mail app disable UISearchBar when in edit mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Using a `SearchDisplayController` and couldn't find any methods that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`UISearchDisplayDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchDisplayDelegate) and the [`UISearchBarDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for knowing when the search bar is in edit mode.

Here is some code to add an overlay over the searchBar, which I've adapted from this [example](http://jduff.github.com/2010/03/01/building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview/),

In your .h file,

```
@interface ...
{
    UIView *disableViewOverlay;
    ...
}

@property(retain) UIView *disableViewOverlay;
```

And in the .m file,

```
@synthesize disableViewOverlay;

...

-(void) disableSearchBar 
{
    self.disableViewOverlay = [[UIView alloc]
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f,44.0f)];
    self.disableViewOverlay.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;

    self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:self.disableViewOverlay];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeIn" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0.4;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) enableSearchBar 
{
    [disableViewOverlay removeFromSuperview];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You can adjust the alpha values until it appears the way you want it to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi, i am familiar with the delegates you mentioned however i am interested in how to visually disable the searchbar These delegates only deal with events related to the searchbar/searching.

Answer (score 5):

Try this when switching to Edit mode:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.alpha = .5;
```

Reverse with:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.alpha = 1.0;
```

You can also animate the alpha change for extra credit :)